# Add plotLine in chartist.js

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, chartist.js, angular-chartist.js

I am looking for best practice of implementing a plotLine as done in HighCharts using Chartist.js.

The Highcharts example is http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-color/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],

            plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 2,
                value: 5.5
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

I don't see such option in the documentation, so is custom svg element (path/line) the right direction?

Comment: that link doesnt work. shows a blank output.

Comment: hm...the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-color/) seems to open ok for me

Comment: i dont think it's natively available in chartist.